# How to create a simple 6 column table in Latex?

Tags: tables, sharelatex

I am struggling in figuring out how to create a 6 column table that fits in my latex file. Note that I do not want to increase the width of the margins. I just want a simple table with 6 columns and 13 rows. I am very new to Latex, my apologies for possibly a trivial answer.

Comment: You could have a look at this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Using_booktabs or an online generator, which could help you a bit. http://www.tablesgenerator.com ProTip: use `booktabs` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of documentation about tables. [This](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) is a really good starting point.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell \\
 cell & cell & cell & cell & cell & cell
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I you need a caption, place the `tabular` environment in a `table` environment.

Comment: You shouldn't use the last `\\ ` unless you add a horizontal line.

Comment: You're right. That was a quick copy-paste. Fixed now

Comment: @JefferyShivers This is exactly what I want however I think due to the slightly longer numbers in each row, the last column has a thick vertical line from the first row to the last row. I think it's because the table is slightly larger then the margin?

Comment: @Teodorico I can't look into that without a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). There are many ways of reformatting a table, and I am happy to help you. If it is sensitive info, just replace the details with garbage text that still recreates the problem, and share that version.

Comment: However, it may be best to ask for help with your new problem in a whole new question (but also search to see if the question/answer has been posted online previously - they often have!).

Comment: @JefferyShivers Consider the column titles to be 10 characters in length, 2nd, 3rd, 4th row the number of digits are 222.3456543, and the 1st, 5th, 6th rows to be at most 11 characters in length. This causes a vertical black bar on the right side. I'd take a screenshot but I'm not sure how to post that here.